# python regex sub does not replace all occurrence

Tags: python, regex

I am using re.sub to remove certain part of the text. there suppose to be multiple matches, but sub function only replace one occurrence per one execution. What is going on?

```
import re
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000155837018000535/0001558370-18-000535.txt')
text = r.content.decode()
reg = re.compile('<DOCUMENT>\n<TYPE>(XML|GRAPHIC|ZIP|EXCEL|PDF)[\s\S]*?(</DOCUMENT>)')

re.findall(reg, text) 

``
output: [('GRAPHIC', '</DOCUMENT>'),
 ('GRAPHIC', '</DOCUMENT>'),
 ('XML', '</DOCUMENT>'),
 ('XML', '</DOCUMENT>'),...]
``

for i in range(10):
    text = re.sub(reg, '', text, re.MULTILINE)
    print(len(text))
``
output: 41875141
40950114
37558399
36097349
34776527``
```

In the first code block, I download the txt file and did a findall. there are multiple occurrence in this file. but when I use re.sub, it only replace one occurence.

**EDIT**

Seems that adding flag re.MULTILINE prevent the replace. Is there a way to get around?

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak I don't think so. if you do a findall() on his example, you only get one match. But in this example, I got multiple matches, but sub() is not working properly.

Comment: You basically set `count` to a non-zero value, which prevents from sub() from replacing all occurences, I think

Comment: A @EvgenyPogrebnyak implied, it should be `flags=re.MULTILINE` in the `re.compile`, not the `re.sub`.

Comment: with @cdarke: `text = re.sub(reg, '', text, count=0, flags=re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak: I edited my comment, you can't specify flags in `re.sub` with a compiled RE.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak: your suggestion will give this error: cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern

Comment: The prize goes to @cdarke ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.MULTILINE` should be specified with the `flags` keyword.  The position you chose happens to be the `count` parameter - the number of matches replaced (`re.MULTILINE` has the integer value 8).

However, with a compiled RE you cannot specify `flags` with `re.sub` but specify `flags = re.MULTILINE` in the `re.compile` instead.

```
reg = re.compile('<DOCUMENT>\n<TYPE>(XML|GRAPHIC|ZIP|EXCEL|PDF)[\s\S]*?(</DOCUMENT>)', flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Let alone the question being a dupe, why do you suggest to use `re.MULTILINE` with `'<DOCUMENT>\n<TYPE>(XML|GRAPHIC|ZIP|EXCEL|PDF)[\s\S]*?(</DOCUMENT>)'` pattern that has neither `^` nor `$`? The real solution is to remove the argument altogether.